# WebStorm incorrectly marking source files as excluded when going from TS to JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a React project that is a mix of JavaScript+Flow and TypeScript -- and I am in the process of iteratively refactoring the JS files to TS/TSX.

In my workflow I'm sometimes going to-and-fro between Git branches, and in these branches, I may have renamed a specific JS file like `App.js` to `App.tsx` and in another unrelated branch, it is still called `App.js`.

I've noticed that when I convert `App.js` to `App.tsx`, everything is fine, but when I toggle back to the branch that still has it set as `App.js`, WebStorm for whatever reason has the JS file marked as ignored from indexing and I have no idea how to set it back to be included as part of indexing while I am working in other git branches that do not have the file renamed -- it is now forever excluded outside of the TSX branch. I've tried invalidating the caches to force reindexing but that did not resolve the issue. Below are some screenshots of what I'm talking about.

[image: WebStorm Image 1]

[image: WebStorm Image 2]

I hope all of that was clear. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: I guess it's because WebStorm treats the .js file as "generated" file now (.jsx is a source, .js is a generated/compiled from the source). Cannot really help on how to resolve it though (not a JS person myself) .. but have a look at `Generated files` entry in the `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries` (select and click on `Edit" button to see the list of files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, related to auto-excluding `.js` files generated by the built-in compiler from indexing, [WEB-30895](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30895).
As a workaround, try removing these `.js` files from `"exactExcludedFiles"` list in `.idea/workspace.xml`,  `<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">` section, like:

```
<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">
    <option name="version" value="1" />
    <option name="exactExcludedFiles">
      <list>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/path/to/App.js" />
        ...
      </list>
    </option>
  </component>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! After applying this change, I had to restart WebStorm for it to take effect. Works like a charm!